# css class toggle not toggling class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to toggle my class once clicked but i am having trouble doing so - if anyone can point out what i am missing or doing wrong that would be great.

```
<a class="rGroupIcons icon-plus addUsersToGroup float_right" href="#" data-bind="attr: { 'data-user-id': ID()}"></a>
<div class="Roles fade in" data-bind="foreach: $parent.Roles()">
     <a style="display: none;" class="roleType btn addUsersWithGroupRole" data-bind="text: RoleTypeName, attr: { 'data-roletype-id': RoleId() }"></a>
                                </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.addUsersToGroup', function (event) {
            $(".addUsersToGroup", $(this)).toggleClass("icon-plus icon-minus");
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use $(this) as at the moment you are looking for .addUsertsToGroup within the element addUsertsToGroup

```
$(document).on('click', '.addUsersToGroup', function (event) {
           $(this).toggleClass("icon-plus icon-minus");
        });
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/domjgreen/NLYNK/

Comment: thanks that worked great. Also i was wondering if i wanted to add the feature that when i have one toggle on showing div and i go and click on another icon it will collapse the previous div